# Como inserir um dado na última linha da lista no R?

Tags: r

Tenho uma lista com alguns dados e necessito fazer a média móvel dos 3 últimos dados disponíveis, o que não estou conseguindo fazer é incluir o valor dessa média na última linha da minha lista. Já tentei utilizar o `merge`, mas está criando uma lista com duas variáveis, da seguinte forma e gostaria que o valor fosse adicionado abaixo da última linha da coluna `x`.

```
x <- c(1:20)
media <- mean(tail(x, n = 3L))
x <- merge(x,media)

x    y
1   19
2   19
3   19
4   19
5   19
6   19
7   19
8   19
9   19
10  19
11  19
12  19
13  19
14  19
15  19
16  19
17  19
18  19
19  19
20  19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer médias móveis, o melhor é usar uma das funções `roll*` do pacote `zoo`. Neste caso vou usar `rollmeanr`, onde o `r` final significa que as médias móveis são alinhadas à direita. Isto deve-se ao pedido de serem as médias dos 3 últimos dados disponíveis.

```
x <- 1:20
y <- zoo::rollmeanr(x, 3, na.pad = TRUE)
```

Agora, qualquer das duas formas de criar uma tabela de dois vetores do mesmo tamanho dá o resultado pretendido. A diferença é que a primeira dá um objeto de classe `"matrix"` e a segunda um objeto de classe `"data.frame"`.

```
cbind(x, y)
data.frame(x, y)
```

## Edição.

Lendo a pergunta melhor, o que é pedido é simplesmente

```
media <- mean(tail(x, n = 3L))
x <- c(x, media)
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado!